# How to connect to home Wifi faster?

Tags: wireless

My Wifi is working great, the connection itself is fast and stable, but one problem is that before the connection is established I have to wait 10-50 seconds usually. Sometimes it will not connect for minutes, you may need to click "disconnect" and then "connect" again.

In the same room, my iOS and Android phones connect to the same Wifi point in about one second.

Can there anything be done about it?

I am using `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver. `nm-applet` or `nmcli`. I also used wpa_supplicant, same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your wifi's signal on your device's wifi menu, maybe is your device can get signal by your wifi hotspot but your device can't send data back to your wifi hotspot. Because the signal has been block down by your wall, so that is why you can connect to your WiFi hotspot in short secands when you and your WiFi hotspot in the same room.

I usually have same problem when I at my school.

Comment: The wifi-router is on the same table as my computer, so this is not the case, indeed.